# Initialization of local variable in C controlled by a mutex

Tags: c, function

I have encountered a problem regarding initialization of local variable in C.
The code is following:

```
BOOL IsBitSet(uint32_t BitAddr)
{
    uint32_t word, index, mask, word_value;
    BOOL retval = FALSE;

    word   = GetWordValue(BitAddr);   // index of the logic word in bits array
    index  = GetIndex(BitAddr, word); // index of the bit in logic word
    mask = (1 << index);              // mask for the bit


    // get the logic word value
    // osOK = 0x0
    if(!osMutexWait(m_BitsArrayMutex, 100)){
        word_value = (*(m_BitsArray + word));
        osMutexRelease(m_BitsArrayMutex);
    }

    // test the bit
    if((word_value & mask) >> index){
        retval = TRUE;
    }else{
        retval = FALSE;
    }

    return retval;
}
```

The problem is that the compiler creates an error message

> error: 'word_value' may be used uninitialized in this function"

I understand the reason of this
error message but I don't know how to resolve this issue. I don't know what 
should be the correct initialization value for the local variable `word_value`.
Does anybody have any idea how to appropriately resolve this problem?

Comment: Just initialize the variable to zero on definition?

Comment: What happens when `osMutexWait()` does not return zero? -> `word_value` will be used unitialized.

Comment: Since you haven't told us a thing about what you expect this code to do, we can't actually help you. The correct initialisation value hinges upon that logic which you have not explained to us. Additionally, the `mutex` tag is irrelevant here, as you could comment it out and still have the same problem you've described.

Comment: If you know the reason for this message, can you explain it? If yes please explain why you can not initialize the variable.

Comment: If we search for the error you quote, [this question is a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20526053/c-warning-withdrawal-amt-may-be-used-uninitialized-in-this-function)...

Comment: You should handle the case when `osMutexWait` returns something else than zero.

Comment: Usually, the auto variables by default hold garbage, so it's better to initialize to `zero` or `specific value`

Comment: What do you want to return if osMutexWait fails?

Comment: A couple notes unrelated to your specific question: `(*(m_BitsArray + word))` is written more idiomatically as `m_BitsArray[word]` and `if((word_value & mask) >> index)` is equivalent to `if (word_value & mask)`.

Comment: @Mulliganaceous The boolean type in C is `_Bool`, which can have values `1` or `0`. But if you like, you can use `stdbool.h` to enable the macros `bool`, `false` and `true`. Anything else is non-standard.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know what is the appropriate initialization value. This value will be used in case the mutex won't be released in prescribed time interval.